# How to keep img saved to PictureBox even if I close the window

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Can somebody help me on how to keep image saved in picturebox after uploading image in picturebox from database. My problem is that everything works except that image disappears after I close the window and I need to click the button to display it, how can the image be automatically shown in picture box after Its been uploaded?

Here's my code for Upload on click:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DB Connection string
    string strConn;
    strConn = "Data Source=MARINCHI\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=login1;Integrated Security=True";
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        conn.Open();

        //Retriver img from DB into Dataset
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, image FROM user2 ORDER BY id", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqlDA.Fill(ds, "image");
        int c = ds.Tables["image"].Rows.Count;

        if (c > 0)
        {
            Byte[] bytIMGDATA = new Byte[0];
            bytIMGDATA = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["image"].Rows[c - 1]["image"]);
            using (MemoryStream stmIMGDATA = new MemoryStream(bytIMGDATA))
            {                 
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stmIMGDATA);


            }
            MessageBox.Show("File read from database succesfully");
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Also I tried to add below the link (`pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stmIMGDATA);`)

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(stmIMGDATA, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
```

and then I get an Error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx) Documentation for Image.FromStream you should have  noticed this:

> **Remarks** 
>   You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.
>   The stream is reset to zero if this method is called successively with
>   the same stream.

Your problem is that your `MemoryStream` will be disposed after `Image.FromStream` will be done.

UPDATE
Here is example how you can do it. I was loading image from File so you have to change my FileStream to MemoryStream to fit to your case:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string picturePath = @"c:\Users\IIG\Desktop\download.png";
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(picturePath))
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            _memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(_memoryStream);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _memoryStream.Close();
            _memoryStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            //do some exception handling
        } 
    }
}
```

In this example image will remain loaded in pictureBox until the form is not closed. On closing event of the Form you have to Close and Dispose your MemoryStream.

Comment: Can you lead me onto how can I keep the image there "forever"? Thanks

Comment: @Rin I have added example how to load Image on button click so that Image remain loaded until the form is not closed

Comment: I think thats what I already had before you posted :O I was wondering on how I can keep img there forever AFTER I close the form and open it so its still there.

Comment: @Rin you can put this code in Form's Load event and the pictureBox will load every time Form is Loaded and you won't need to click on button

Comment: @Rin try my update. This will load image when form is opened.

Comment: I applied my code just as you shown and its working! Thanks alot for the help bro! :))))

Comment: @Rin what do you mean by saying nothing happened? Can you add your code what you last tried to question

Comment: I figured what I did wrong! I applied my code again just as you shown and its working! Thanks alot for the help bro! :))))